# Excluding entities from Swagger model

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, swagger

We are using Swagger to model our API with Spring annotations:

```
@Operation(summary = "Creates a post for given user.")
@PostMapping("/post")
open fun createPost(
    @RequestParam("userId") user: User,
)
```

The issue we are having is that Swagger does not know there is a logic behind and we are only passing `userId: Long` for which the user is loaded by Hibernate.

The model of `User` contains several `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToMany` relations to other entities and Swagger builds the model of `User` with all of them. This causes the model to be huge and some of our Swagger docs wouldn't even load in the browser as the model is in the size of megabytes.

Is there a way to tell Swagger:

- to ignore specific entity/entities
- to enforce different type (in this case `Long`)

Ideally something like:

```
@Operation(summary = "Creates a post for given user.")
@PostMapping("/post")
open fun createPost(
    @SwaggerType(Long::class)
    @RequestParam("userId") 
    user: User,
)
```

Comment: I think you should ignore the @Operation annotation for the entities that you want to exclude

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense. I want to keep the `@Operation` and its description. Please read what I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way is to use Springfox with an alternate type rule. See no 10 in the examples given here:
https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-spring-mvc-and-spring-boot

This enables you to completely replace your User class by **any** other (fake) class that you want to show to the Swagger user, without polluting your model with workarounds - but still staying transparent in your code.

Comment: Do you mean the `10.1.1. JacksonSerializerConvention`?

Comment: No need to go into Serialization. Just use new Docket(...).alternateTypeRules(AlternateTypeRules.newRule(typeResolver.resolve(Foo.class), typeResolver.resolve(Bar.class))). This will replace all occurences of Foo to Bar. Please note that this will only affect your Swagger documentation, not the endpoint itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options that can be tried:

1. Using inheritance with User Model, you can just define a SuperClass-childClass mapping with User class only containing the userId, and the child class that inherits from it will be holding the other attributes for you. In this way, the input will only be the userId with minimal effort.
2. Using JsonIgnore, but this works really well while returning the response.
3. With OpenAPI, Swagger has introduced the capability to use specific properties from the request class. More can be read from
   https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/

Comment: The problem is that this is fully done with annotations. I am not sure how to do it with them - this would only be feasible with manual definitions.

Comment: then in that situation, i would suggest you to go for inheritance model. This will be the least manual effort, with max efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two different class,a basic class and a senior class,and the senior extends the basic,use basic class in API;

or you can use @JsonIgnore if you don't want to show the field ,like:

```
@JsonIgnore
private String name;
```

Beacuse Swagger use jackson to json, if you shield the field by jackson,it will not appear.

In swagger
you can use `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)`,This is the perfect way

Comment: This is not what I want, this would prevent me serializing these enitties.

Comment: you can use  @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true), this only work in swagger.